# Python: Alternative to looping through 60000 rows

Tags: python, excel, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 excel files. 
File 1 Description:
- Frequency of data: 1Hz
- Total rows: 62,000

File 2 Description:
- Frequency of data: 10 Hz
- Total rows: 616,000

Task at hand:

To combine both sets of data, using averages of 10 data points for the same second for File 2.

The first column in both files is a Timestamp and data is recorded for the same duration of time. However, the timestamps are not identical and always differ in the milliseconds.

My Approach:
I use pandas to read in the excel files as Dataframes.

I have been able to use for loops to accomplish this for smaller data sets. However, because of the volume of data, using a for loop is very cumbersome and slow. 
In order to do the rolling average of 10 points for each second in file 2, I had previously used nested for loops. Again because of the nature of the data, it is nearly impossible to use the same method.

I will appreciate any help on the methodology to approach this issue.

Comment: you could just `resample` the 2nd df and then truncate the datetimes so the milliseconds don't matter as you're resampling 10 hz to match the 1hz sampling so you could drop the milliseconds component

Comment: From my understanding, `resample` requires a constant timedelta. Although there are 10 data points per second, the timedelta varies by about 2-3% each time the data is recorded.

Comment: Well you have to decide how to bucket your data, whether the 2-3% matters difference is up to you. You can't make an exact match anyway so you need to come up with some strategy to merge your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign groups to your large dataframe based on groups of ten, then use groupby to get the mean values.

```
df_big['group'] = [i // 10 for i in range(len(df_big))]  # Python 2 truncation.
df_big.groupby('group').mean()
```

If you provide some sample data of the two files, I can refine this answer.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. However, there is still the issue of relating the data from df_big to df_small. As it stands, I cannot run a true/false algorithm to check where the timestamp matches. I would like to be able to combine the data from both files.

Comment: That's why I need to see some data.  Try df_big.head() and df_small.head()